# webpack react error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gulp, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader

Webpack compiling errors for react files. The compiler seems to throw errors on every react file with the following:

```
ERROR in ./public/react-components/modules/user/profile/edit.js
Module parse failed: /Workspace/bungaloow/public/react-components/modules/user/profile/edit.js Unexpected token (5:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Webpack configuration:

```
var glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {
    entry: glob.sync('./public/react-components/**/*.{js,json}'),
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/compiled',
        filename: "react-components.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', query: {presets: ['es2015','react']}}
        ],
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                use: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    watch: true
};
```

Comment: Why isn't your babel-loader and JSX test in your rules?

Comment: i've added it to my rules, will update, still encountering same error

Comment: IIRC entry should be an object not an array in 2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing Webpack 1 syntax (`module.loaders`) with Webpack 2 syntax (`module.rules`). My guess is that you're using Webpack 2 and it's only using `module.rules`, so your `babel-loader` isn't configured properly.

I believe the correct Webpack 2 syntax would be this:

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test   : /\.json$/,
    loader : 'json-loader' // `use` is appropriate when you have to chain loaders,
                           // if there's only a single loader, use `loader`
  }, {
    test    : /\.js$/,
    loader  : 'babel-loader',
    options : { presets : ['es2015', 'react'] }
  }]
}
```

More info [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules).